# Terminal beep change

Tags: command-line, sound, teminal-bell

Alright so I found a few questions like this, but they were not what I was looking for.

I am looking to change the terminal beep, so the one that plays when I am in the terminal and press tab. I found a few that said it was in `/usr/share/sounds` but I couldn't find the beep it does in the terminal there.

So if someone could help would be very much appreciated!